# ARCore Tablet Support

Tags: tablet, arcore

I would like to know whether ARCore supports any tablets natively as of the latest update.

I have found the list of supported phones [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices), however no mentions of tablets seem to be made.

Other similar questions on StackOverflow seem to have had no conclusive answer.

Comment: Have you ask this question at superuser.com ?

Comment: Hey, no I have not posted on superuser.com, however I have looked for the answer on it and couldn't find anything.

Comment: if a device in not in the list of supported devices, then it is not officially supported. Therefore, if no tablet is on there, ARCore does not officially support any of them as of today

Comment: try downloading arCore1.2.apk and install directly on your tablet. It will work fine for devices 7.0 and above.

Comment: it may not work if your tablet's processor arm version is not supported

Comment: Did anyone test arcore on their android tablet? Isn't it super silly they support iPad and not android tablets ?

Comment: WARNING for anyone considering a Galaxy Tab S3 for ARCore: at time of writing (Feb 18, 2019) and building with Unity and ARCore SDK for Android v1.6.0, AR apps are effectively unusable. v1.7.0 of the SDK is now available, but it's unlikely to have remedied the situation. Tracking stability is abysmal, and anchors are frequently lost. We did a direct comparison with a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (using the same APK), which was ROCK solid. It's a real shame, as we were hoping to present a 'big screen' version of augmented reality. But there's a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, tablets have made it onto the list of [officially supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices): Galaxy Tab S3, Galaxy Tab S4, Acer Chromebook Tab 10